# SSL error when trying to open Jupyter server on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, jupyter-notebook

I am using windows 10, and configure my aws configuration followed tutorial here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dlami/latest/devguide/setup-jupyter.html

The TCP/IP port has been open for 8888, so is my putty connection add the tunnel for 8888. Yet still when I access the Jupyter from browser, I have error says:
This page isn’t working 127.0.0.1 didn’t send any data.

When I looked at server side, there's an SSL error, how do I proceed to open the jupyter notebook from browser ?
[image]

Comment: Are you adding the port number in the URL?

Comment: yes, I use localhost:8888 and 127.0.0.1:8888, also tried https://ip-172-31-19-217:8888 as indicated in log.